# Router malfunction due to electric fluctuations?

Tags: power

As I'm studying computer engineering I'm the tech support at most of my family, including my grandparents. When going there this evening, I didn't get internet on my phone. They have been having trouble with internet off and on for quite a while now, and apparently they had that problem three times earlier today. After a quick check it turns out DHCP isn't working, as setting a static IP gives internet access right away.

A lengthy phone-call to the provider turned up nothing, as before they could find anything the DHCP magically started working again. Not a clue why.

A bit later my grandparents mention the TV showing errors when flicking light switches every so often. But of course, as it's random, it seems impossible to reproduce while I'm around.

These two issues got me thinking, could the cause of both issues be in the power lines? Maybe a small change in current could cause the modem router to malfunction, causing both TV and DHCP malfunctions.

Now being an IT-guy, I've got only a small bit of insight into electronics. My three questions therefore are:

1. Has anybody ever heard of a case like this?
2. Does my theory sound plausible?
3. How could I check if this is the cause? And if so, how could I remedy it?

As a possibly important side-note, the house they live in is about 50/60 years old, as would the wiring be. It's originally built for the old Dutch 220V AC, which has been replaced by 230V AC.

Comment: No, I have never heard of a case of magic that makes only dhcp not work. You should better start debugging this on the network level. Have you tried switching the router on and off? ^^

Comment: Check your router model against vulnerability databases. The last two years crackers got thousands of routers, cameras and other IoT that behave pretty badly if it was hacked. It also a pretty good advise  in answers to use UPS for such devices

Comment: Similarly strange router/modem problems have often been solved by replacing the power pack for the offending device. Your theory of an electrical cause may be on the right track, but it could be the power pack failing and becoming overly sensitive to fluctuations in the supply line.

Comment: @PlasnaHH that always works, but then after a while it fails again

Comment: It might be prudent to seek firmware updates for that DHCP host.

Answer (score 0):

Power glitches can potentially cause all sorts of random problems with a router, although it's more likely going to cause a reset than a partial failure.  Very brief power interruptions (less than a tenth of a second or so) will probably not cause problems.  It's hard to know.  I would get a small UPS (Uninterruptable Power Supply) and plug the router into that.  This will protect against most power spikes and dropouts.

But this DHCP-only failure is probably not a power-glitch problem.